# How to copy a file glob with directory structure

Tags: ruby, glob, file-copying

I want to copy selected build products, preserving their part of the directory structure, but this:

```
Dir.chdir('build/sources/ios_src') {
  FileUtils.cp_r(Dir.glob('build/Build/Products/*/*.app*'), '/tmp/bcsh')
}
```

results in

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir - /tmp/bcsh/Booble.app
```

despite the glob returning this:

```
Dir.chdir('build/sources/ios_src') {
  Dir.glob('build/Build/Products/*/*.app*')
}
 => ["build/Build/Products/Calabash-iphonesimulator/Booble.app",
     "build/Build/Products/Calabash-iphonesimulator/Booble.app.dSYM"]
```

I want `/tmp/bsch/build/Build/Products/.../Booble.app` and `.../Booble.app.dSYM` not `/tmp/bcsh/Booble.app` and `/tmp/bcsh/Booble.app.dSYM`.

For clarity, I'm capable of creating a directory, but the error more usefully shows that the files would end up where I don't want them than more verbiage.

Comment: `Dir.mkdir('/tmp/bcsh')` in advance will help. If you want to copy files with the full path, you should create all the directories yourself. E.g. use `Dir.glob() { |filename| HERE! Dir.mkdir && FileUtils.cp }`

Comment: @mudasobwa What's 'HERE!'? Is it a thing, or just you showing me where directories get created? I get so confused by Ruby's weird magic that I can't tell functionality from shorthand. Can you craft this as an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Thanks to mudasobwa for the hint about glob taking a block. This seems to copy the results of the glob, preserving both the directory structure OF the glob and within each entry:

```
Dir.chdir('build/sources/ios_src') {
  Dir.glob('build/Build/Products/*/*.app*') { |file|
    dest = File.dirname("/tmp/bcsh/#{file}")
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(dest) && FileUtils.cp_r(file, dest)
  }
}
```

Not keen on the temporary, but

```
.... { |file|
  FileUtils.cp_r(file, FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname("/tmp/bcsh/#{file}")).first)
}
```

is a bit extreme.

Comment: The use of `dest` as a temporary variable is fine since you're using it twice in the following line. If you only used it once it'd be questionable. As is you're getting a minor speed up because of the multiple uses. More questionable is the use of `&&` to join the two operations. Idiomatic code would reverse the operation using a trailing `if` to `mkdir_p` before `cp_r`: `FileUtils.cp_r(file, dest) if FileUtils.mkdir_p(dest)`. `&&` used that way smells of C or Perl.

Comment: It looks like you're doing too much work though. `cp_r` recursively copies the hierarchy under the starting directory: "...If src is a directory, this method copies all its contents recursively.", so using `glob` shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @theTinMan I don't want the entire heirarchy though: I only want the things with .app in them, in any of the directories immediately under Products. The glob gives me the roots of the things I want.

Comment: @theTinMan And yes, I'm definitely not a devout Ruby programmer even after 18 months. There are certainly some good bits, but I still feel like I'm programming in a briar patch riddled with rabbit holes and occasional glitter compared to C++/Perl/Java/Groovy (and even Python, now it has optional typing).

Comment: Local variable here might be eliminated with [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-tap): `File.dirname("/tmp/bcsh/#{file}").tap { |dest| ... }`. That way is preferred since it makes it easier/faster for GC to collect `dest`.

Comment: You might want to look at using Ruby's [`Find.find`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) class and method. It makes it easy to do a recursive descent looking at individual files, and won't hit the disk as hard. It's well worth knowing about and using for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dir.chdir('build/sources/ios_src') do
  Dir.glob('build/Build/Products/*/*.app*') do |filename|
    dir = File.join("/tmp/bcsh", *filename.split(File::SEPARATOR)[0...-1])

    FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir)
    FileUtils.cp(filename, dir)
  end
end
```

Comment: You might want to look at `*filename.split(File::SEPARATOR)[0..-1]` and what it's doing in the `File.join` context. You're making Ruby do things it doesn't need to do.

Comment: @theTinMan indeed, thanks, there should’ve been triple-dot range. Fixed.

Comment: Is split()[0...-1] more efficient or clearer than File.dirname? And does use of File::SEPARATOR matter, given that my glob has / in it?

Comment: @android.weasel not at all. Using `File::SEPARATOR` is a matter of good habit, I always use it in file-related operations, just in case.

Comment: `File.dirname` is MUCH clearer than using `split` and using `[0...-1]`. The later requires people to understand that `split` against a filename returns the path as an array, which then has to be passed to `join` whereas `dirname` returns the string already joined. Also `[0...-1]` is extremely unintuitive because of `...`. The use of `...` is discouraged because it is easily misread. At a minimum it should be written as `0..-2` but `dirname` would still be much more readable. And, readability always improves maintainability.

Comment: `"there should’ve been triple-dot range"`. No, `dirname` should have been used rather than `split` then `join`. File's filename methods are very flexible and it's really good to experiment with them to learn how flexible they are.

Comment: @theTinMan I never trust 3rd party file path handling routines. Even when they are provided by language core. This is my own brainbug, but it is induced by my experience. Sooner or later you’ll find yourself debugging path routines on, say, VAX/VMS, or DR-DOS, or whatever.

Comment: The "3rd party" routines use the same technique your code does, but under the covers. They're aware of the file path delimiters so they're cross-platform aware. Remember, the IO class automatically converts between platform file path delimiters.

Comment: @theTinMan in theory I know that. In practice, I have read “cross-platform aware” twice as often as the tools were in fact cross-platform aware. I understand, that it’s silly to expect the same weird behaviour from ruby, but since they ruined `__callee__` _for the whole 2.3 version lifetime_, I don’t trust the core team anymore.